# jslint options doesn't seem to work on aptana 3

Tags: aptana, jslint

I'm having trouble with jslint, for example when I set the option 'white: true' on aptana, I get even more errors about indentation! but on jslint.com I don't get those messages, the option there works.

Just wondering, is this a known bug, or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I have in the beginning of the file:
/*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true*/

...and 200+ warning messages :p

Comment: It's a little hard to tell....I would recommend filing a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
/jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true/
```

should be

```
/*jslint browser: true, vars: true, white: true */
```

BTW, if you go to jslint.org and set the options you want, it produces the exact string you'll need.